# where is a pci driver's probe function called in the linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, pci

I browsed the __pci_register_driver() in pci-driver.c, but can't find the pci driver's probe() get called there. Which kernel function will call this probe() instead? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the same file pci-driver.c there is a function called

```
static long local_pci_probe(void *_ddi)
{
...
    rc = ddi->drv->probe(ddi->dev, ddi->id);
...
}
```

The call originates from `struct bus_type pci_bus_type = { .probe = pci_device_probe }`. First, `pci_device_probe()` calls `__pci_device_probe()`,  which calls `pci_call_probe()`, which calls `local_pci_probe()`, which then calls the pci driver's `probe()`.

Answer (score 0):

- prototype of _pci_register_driver is given in **pci.h** as follow:

  *#define pci_register_driver(driver)  __pci_register_driver(driver, THIS_MODULE, KBUILD_MODNAME)*
- __pci_register_driver is defined in pci-driver.c
- In some condition **pci.h** file is included in driver file and called by pci_register_driver function.There it is used..